# Aligning article elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html5 page I'm trying to style a group of articles. The article-elements have a fixed width but a variable height. I tried using float: left.

It should look like the green boxes below, but it looks like the red boxes. Box nr 3 is not aligned properly.

Any CSS3 or even js way to fix this?

[image: situation]

Comment: What did you use? share the css you're using now

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/NjFjy/. The code is pretty simple but I have no idea how to wrap it as I want.

Comment: I was going to ask same question: +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plug-in for jQuery called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) that is designed to do this.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what's needed. And there's even a mootools port :-) Thanks!

Comment: though I was thinking about some reverse-gravity-enabling JS, that would pull divs up, but what the heck, will try this. thanks.