# Fill tiles one by one even different width and height

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please refer the image, I think once you see realize the issue.

I tested this tiles in two ways, like UL,LI list and by set of DIVs but none of was success. I just added float:left but as you see, in the third row, after the tall tile, forth row items does not fill to space.

Please change the name if not right meaning and googled but couldn't find should be my keyword want rich. Please guide me.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning article elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143103/aligning-article-elements)

Comment: Where's the HTML and CSS that you tried?

Comment: This is why it's important to keep an empty column on the side, so you can slide the long pieces down and clear four rows at once. ...Or maybe I'm thinking of something else.

Comment: @Diodeus Yes that was the answer for my issue, thanks for the hand... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [JQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for designing like this.

Using its CSS along with JQuery you should be easily able to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`html`

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan=2></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

`css`

```
table {background:black;}
td {background:blue;width:40px;height:40px;}​
```