# How do I display image flush with other images after a clear?

Tags: css, css-float

I've included a screen shot of what I currently have and how I want it fixed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUKLu.png

Here is the simplified HTML code for my project (I have 19 images that I'm building in a complex grid and so I'm only including the trouble images since the others are playing nice together):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="images">
        <div class="col col-1-3">
            <div class="module" id="img-10">
                <img src="img/pic_10.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-1-3 clear">
            <div class="module" id="img-11">
                <img src="img/pic_11.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-1-3">
            <div class="module" id="img-12">
                <img src="img/pic_12.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-1-3">
            <div class="module" id="img-13">
                <img src="img/pic_13.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--.images -->
</div><!--.wrapper -->
```

Img 11 has a clear so that it will tuck itself under image 10, but then I can't get img 12 and 13 to go level with image 10.  If I don't do the clear on img-11, it will be side by side with img-10.

Here is my CSS:

```
* { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box:
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.grid {
    overflow: hidden;
}
    .col{
        float: left;
    }
    .col-1-5 {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .col-1-3 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .col-2-5 {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .col-2-3 {
        width: 66.6666%;
    }
    .col-3-5 {
        width: 60%;
    }
.module img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
}
#img-10 {
    height: 194px;
    width: 333.33px;
}
#img-11 {
    height: 194px;
    width: 333.33px;
}
#img-12,
#img-13 {
    height: 388px;
    width: 333.33px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

UPDATE: I got help from a friend on a different site and using this code instead works:

```
<div class="col col-1-3">
    <div class="module" id="img-10">
        <img src="img/pic_10.png">
    </div>
    <div class="module" id="img-11">
        <img src="img/pic_11.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676227/fill-a-div-width-100-with-same-height-dynamic-width-images

Comment: Please make a http://jsbin.com of your code. If you give the images a border declaration, it doesn't matter that you cannot upload the images themselves there. Please also indicate which image has which number, just to make sure.

Comment: Regarding your -- in principle very much appreciated -- update: please put that in an 'Answer your own question'. Otherwise this question/thread will stay labeled as 'unanswered'. Which is undesirable for a number of reasons.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I tried to answer my own earlier but it said I needed to wait a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I got help from a friend on a different site and using this code instead works:

```
<div class="col col-1-3">
    <div class="module" id="img-10">
       <img src="img/pic_10.png">
    </div>
    <div class="module" id="img-11">
        <img src="img/pic_11.png">
    </div>
</div>
```